# Error in Real Analysis proof about Uniform Convergence and function Continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am struggling to understand what is wrong with this proof for a statement I found. I know that the statement is false because I found a counterexample, but what is actually wrong with the below proof?

“Statement”. If fn : X → Y is a sequence of functions converging uniformly on X to a
function f, and if f is continuous at x0, then there exists N ∈ N such that fn is continuous
at x0 for all n ≥ N.

“Proof”. Let ε > 0. By uniform convergence, we can find N ∈ N such that
∀n ≥ N, ∀x ∈ X : dY (fn(x), f(x)) <
ε
3
.

By continuity of f at x0, we furthermore find δ > 0 such that
∀x ∈ X : dX(x, x0) < δ ⇒ dY (f(x), f(x0)) <
ε
3
.

Hence whenever n ≥ N and dX(x, x0) < δ we get
dY (fn(x), fn(x0)) ≤ dY (fn(x), f(x)) + dY (f(x), f(x0)) + dY (f(x0), fn(x0))
<
ε/3 + ε/3+ε/3
= ε.

Comment: can you give me your counter example?

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra Just take any bounded discontinuous $f$ and consider $f_n=\frac f n$.

Comment: Please write it using $

Answer (score 1):

Your $N$ depends on $\epsilon$. So you have not proved continuity of $f_n$ for any particular $n$.